# how to make a textbox value depends on combobox value same row in the database

Tags: php, combobox, textbox

http://i40.tinypic.com/2qvduzr.jpg    <---- please look at the picture

hi guys, i want to ask a question, how do i make a textbox value depends on combobox selected item?

```
<form action="tambahMk.php" method="post">
    <table border="1" class="statistica"  align="center" width="85%">
      <tr>
        <td width="350" bgcolor="#66FF99"><b>ID Matakuliah</b></td>
        <td align="center" width="" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>:</b></td>
        <td width=""><input type="text" name="idMk" maxlength="9" size="70"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#00FF33"><b>Nama Matakuliah</b></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="namaMk" size="70"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#66FF99"><b>Nama Dosen</b></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>:</b></td>
        <td><select>
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dsn";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<option value='".$row[nama]."'>".$row[nama]."</option>";
            }?>         
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#00FF33"><b>ID Dosen</b></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="idDsn" maxlength="9" readonly size="70"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Tambah" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: you should look into Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="tambahMk.php" method="post">
<table border="1" class="statistica"  align="center" width="85%">
  <tr>
    <td width="350" bgcolor="#66FF99"><b>ID Matakuliah</b></td>
    <td align="center" width="" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>:</b></td>
    <td width=""><input type="text" name="idMk" maxlength="9" size="70"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#00FF33"><b>Nama Matakuliah</b></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="namaMk" size="70"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#66FF99"><b>Nama Dosen</b></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>:</b></td>
    <td><?php
        $result = mysql_query("select * from tbl_dsn");  
        $jsArray = "var idDosen = new Array();\n";  

        echo '<select name="namaDsn" onchange="document.getElementById(\'id_Dsn\').value = idDosen[this.value]">';  
        echo '<option>------ pilih dosen ------</option>';  

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
        echo '<option value="' . $row['nama'] . '">' . $row['nama'] . '</option>';  
        $jsArray .= "idDosen['" . $row['nama'] . "'] = '" . addslashes($row['idDsn']) . "';\n";  
        }  

        echo '</select>';  
        ?>  
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#00FF33"><b>ID Dosen</b></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="idDsn" id="id_Dsn" maxlength="9" readonly size="70"/>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    <?php echo $jsArray; ?>  
    </script> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Tambah" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

it's fixed, i only take onChange event by the textbox id...

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<input type="text" name="idDsn" maxlength="9" readonly size="70">
```

and add the value attribute along with the database field name (I have use $id as an example you will need to look at your code on how you retrieved the data):

```
<input type="text" name="idDsn" maxlength="9" readonly size="70" value='<?php echo $id;?>'>
```

Comment: but it doesn't related to the combobox, does it?

Comment: No but you have already coded that. The only thing missing is the name attribute i.e. <select name='NamaDosen'>

Comment: but it will only make the textbox value stands by itself not by combobox selected item